# Vaadin refresh grid after adding row

Tags: java, grid, refresh, vaadin, vaadin7

My grid is not refreshing automatically after adding a row. I've tried several solutions from other questions but they didn't work. E.g. `grid.clearSortOrder();` and `grid.markAsDirty();`. My goal is to add rows after time periods. Therefore I'm using a Timer and the rows are added but the grid does not refresh until I click in the table.

Easy code example:

```
Grid grid = new Grid();

grid.addColumn("Name");
grid.addColumn("Age");

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
    public void run(){
        grid.addRow("Exmaple","99");    
    }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vaadin callbacks are triggered by user interactions like mouse press on a button, selection of an option and so on. When you need the user interface to reflect a change that was not caused by the mouse/keyboard, you need to enable [server push](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html):

```
@Push
public class App extends UI {

  @Override
  public void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
      public void run() {
        access(() -> grid.addRow("Example", "99"));
      }
    }, 1000, 1000);
  }
}
```

Note the usage of `UI.access(Runnable)` to lock the UI when it is accessed from a non-request thread.

Comment: Works so far. But now I can only add the row out of the UI class right? My table and the data is actually in a class which extends `window`

Comment: When you start your timer you can get a reference to the current UI with `UI.getCurrent()`

Answer (score 3):

You will Need Server push for this. See [Vaadin-Doc-Serverpush](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-push.html).
You want to change the UI from another Thread (Timer.schedule() will execute in another thread).